# How to Get Join Count using Add Join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

ArcGIS Pro 3.0.2

When I do a spatial join one-to-many between polygon and point, I get nice count field that shows how many points landed in my polygon.

Is it possible to replicate this using the `Add Join` or `Join Field` tool with a Feature Class and a Table?

Needed so that I can join a Table to my Polygon based on ID numbers instead of location.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to [create a frequency table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/frequency.htm) based on IDs in my event standalone table, then join it to my Line feature class based on the ID field.